# A question about "Warning: Object directory not changed from original" when executing "make" command

Tags: freebsd, kernel-module

I originally post this issue on [FreeBSD mailing list](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2016-July/272820.html), but unfortunately can't receive any response. So I repost question here, and hope this behavor doesn't violate any conduct code of SO.

I am writing a simple `FreeBSD` kernel module. But after rebooting machine (I am not sure whether this is the reason), I find the "`make`" command can't work, and it always prompts the following words:

```
# make
Warning: Object directory not changed from original /root/hello
```

even though I delete and upload a new file, this issue still exists.

After referring this [post](https://www.mail-archive.com/freebsd-hackers@freebsd.org/msg10678.html), I try "`make obj`"
command, then the "`make`" works:

```
# make obj
/usr/obj/root/hello created for /root/hello
# make
@ -> /usr/src/sys
machine -> /usr/src/sys/amd64/include
x86 -> /usr/src/sys/x86/include
......
```

I can't figure out the root cause behind it:
(1) Why does `make` complain "`Warning: Object directory not changed from original /root/hello`" although I have updated file?
(2) Why "`make obj`" can save "`make`"?

Comment: You should take the "gnu-make" tag off of this, since it's not related to GNU make.  FreeBSD make is very different from GNU make in its details.

Answer (score 0):

After a little reading of `/usr/src/share/mk/bsd.obj.mk`, it seems FreeBSD doesn't want `${.OBJDIR}` to be the same directory as `${.CURDIR}`, as it seems to imply that `${.OBJDIR}` has been constructed incorrectly (or rather, not canonically).

My understanding of *why* the above happens is non-existent, but is fixed by running

```
make clean
```

forcing a clean build next time `make` is run.

*Best of luck friend, hopefully you've solved this yourself in the 2 years, 2 months since this question was posted.*

Answer (score 0):

The FreeBSD convention is to put products of a build ("objects") into a different directory than the source. You can see this in the directory layout of the operating system itself (i.e. `/usr/src` and `/usr/obj`). The warning is pointing out this component is different from the convention, but as it is a warning, it is safe to ignore for out-of-tree builds.

As you discovered, running `make obj` creates an object directory for your component in the canonical location (i.e. `/usr/obj/${.CURDIR}`) and avoids the warning. This may have helped if `/usr/obj` didn't exist as the command would create the required directory structure.

There are a couple of ways to tell the system of Makefiles "I know what I'm doing" and avoid the warning without a directory under `/usr/obj`. The most correct would be to create a local object directory for the build:

```console
$ cd mysrc
$ mkdir obj
$ env MAKEOBJDIR=$(realpath obj) make
```

Note that `MAKEOBJDIR` is an environment variable and not a command line variable.

Another hackier approach would be to tell make there aren't any object files by adding `NO_OBJ= yes` to the Makefile. The build will still produce objects, but `bsd.obj.mk` won't look for the object directory.